# render page is wrong

Tags: python, html, django

When I accessed upload_save method,basic.html was showed.
I wrote(changed into) in view.py like

```
def upload_save(request):

    photo_id = request.POST.get("p_id", "")

    if (photo_id):
        photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)
    else:
        photo_obj = Post()

    files = request.FILES.getlist("files[]")

    photo_obj.image = files[0]

    photo_obj.save()
    return render(request, "registration/accounts/photo.html")

    photos = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'photos': photos,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', context)
```

So,I naturally thought when I accessed upload_save method,photo.html would be showed.
In photo.html,I wrote

```
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  {% for photo in photos %}
    <h2 class="page-header">{{ photo.title }}</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/{{ photo.image1 }}">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/{{ photo.image2 }}">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/{{ photo.image3 }}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'accounts:upload' photo.id %}">UPLOAD</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I wrote
 base.html in photo.html ,but I cannot understand why photo.html's content is not show.
By Google Verification,I found only base.html was showed in my page.(So,photo.html could not be read)
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide `photos` to your template. The `{% for photo in photos %}` is trying to loop over something that has not been provided. You need to add `photos` to the template context like so:

```
# ... rest of your view
photos = Post.objects.all()
context = {'photos': photos}
return render(
    request, "registration/accounts/photo.html", context=context
)
```

Reference: [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Comment: thx ur comments.You told me about in views.py like the additional codes
right?But it didn't work.Is there any wrong point?

Comment: @lili remove the first return in your view.

Comment: By Google Verification,I found only base.html was showed in my page.(So,photo.html could not be read)

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not include block body in base.html. if not included add these lines in base.html where you want to add photo.html content

```
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html should be look like this

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><a href="/">Photo list</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            {% block body %}
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```